# How to substr before mark text?

Tags: php

I want to cut text before "DETAIL" .

```
<?PHP
$text="Name:myproduct Price:99 DETAIL :abcdedsfsdff 21348dfsdf ds "
//i want result Name:myproduct Price:99
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to use `substr` which is used to get the substring of a string along with `strpos` which gives the position of the given occurance:

```
echo substr($text, 0, strpos($text, 'DETAIL'));
```

Visit [php.net](http://php.net/substr)

Comment: @NurmpungUnchalee , you might want to consider one of these answers as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can split the text in array and get the first element of array:

```
$text="Name:myproduct Price:99 DETAIL :abcdedsfsdff 21348dfsdf ds ";
$abc =  explode('DETAIL',$text);
echo $abc[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "Name:myproduct Price:99 DETAIL :abcdedsfsdff 21348dfsdf ds";
$clean = substr($text, 0, stripos($text, "detail"));
echo $clean;
```

This will output

> Name:myproduct Price:99

```
$text = "Name:myproduct Price:99 DETAIL :abcdedsfsdff 21348dfsdf ds";
$clean = substr($text, stripos($text, "detail"), strlen($text) - 1);
echo $clean;
```

This will output

> DETAIL :abcdedsfsdff 21348dfsdf ds